# iscroll horizontal issues

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll4

I have created an app using phonegap, jquery mobile and iscroll with 3 scrolling divs, the first 2 scroll vertically and I am trying to get the third scrolling horizontally, but am having problems. The horizontal is working, as in letting me scroll to the right of the div, however, when i try to scroll further, the div jumps back to the start. I am hoping someone has encountered something similar and has a solution.
My code looks like this;

```
var myScroll, myScroll2, myScroll3;

 $(".scrollArea").live("pageshow", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {vScroll:true, hScroll:false});},0);
        setTmeout(function(){myScroll2 = new iScroll('wrapper2', {vScroll:true, hScroll:false});},0);
        setTimeout(function(){myScroll3 = new iScroll('wrapper3', {vScroll:false, hScroll:true});},0);


                             });


<div data-role="content">
            <div id="wrapper3">
               stuff here...
            </div>
```

I have set the width of the wrapper to 1500px to test the scrolling, but this jumping error is driving me mad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Nope, have decided to ditch JQM and go for Sencha touch 2, does everything I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use jq.scroll.js from github it works for me.
https://github.com/appMobi/jQ.Mobi/tree/master/plugins